# py-spidev and ADNS3080

Tags: raspbian, python, spi

I have been trying a lot to deal with the flow-motion sensor but I couldn't arrive to a clear result. It might be I can't understand the procedure..

I'm using cs1 on raspberry Defining the spi by this code

```
import spidev
import time

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,1)
spi.max_speed_hz = 2000000
```

following this to read the product ID or delta_x I have to send the address and then read so either i use xfer2 or write and then read by the two cases I always get zero or 23 on product ID

```
resp = spi.xfer2([0x00])
```

or

```
spi.writebytes([0x00])
time.sleep(0.001)
resp = spi.readbytes(10)
```

update:

[ADNS3080 datasheet](https://people.ece.cornell.edu/land/courses/ece4760/FinalProjects/s2009/ncr6_wjw27/ncr6_wjw27/docs/adns_3080.pdf)

[py-spidev documentation](http://tightdev.net/SpiDev_Doc.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you link to the spec of the device rather than relying on people to search for you.

The device requires two bytes.

Try `resp = spi.xfer([0, 0])` to read the product id.  The result (23 or 0x17) should be in `resp[1]`.

If that is not reliable you are going to have to drop the speed to accommodate the 50 µs delay between bytes.

Comment: I did update my post, Can you please explain me why the device require two bytes. first address and second the data ?. I did try to read the delta_x using the address 0x03 using xfer but the result is always 0 and by using write and read the result is 23. regarding the time I did the sleep as yo usee down.  `code` resp = spi.xfer([0x03,0x00]) or 
   `code` spi.writebytes([0x03])
    time.sleep(0.000050)
    resp = spi.readbytes(1)

Comment: Doesn't the spec say 2 bytes are required for a read or write on page 16?  Page 17 shows the various delays needed.  Have you cut the speed down to less than 20 kbps?  That would ensure the timing for most commands.  Because of the timing requirements I would use my own GPIO for chip select and toggle it on and off as required.  You might be able to achieve the same effect with xfer2.  You have not explained (in a form I can understand) which, if any,  commands are working and which are not.

Comment: I changed the wiring to toggle the cs. if I type this code only it gives me zero for Product ID  `code` GPIO.output(cs, GPIO.LOW)
    spi.writebytes([0x00])
    resp = spi.readbytes(1)
    GPIO.output(cs, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(0.00015) but if I add this code before `code` GPIO.output(cs, GPIO.LOW)
    #resp = spi.xfer2([0x00,0])
    #print resp[1]
    GPIO.output(cs, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(0.00015)
the second request and the first request gives 23.  I can't find the logic behind this behavior and I don't know why it gives zero for delta_x

Comment: small update:  the problem was the lens it required more light to respond.

Comment: @Feras That's good.  If you can get it to work reliably you could answer your own question with the details.  That would be useful for people who come across the question.

Comment: I'll come back soon with full details.